# Change in the value of $f(z)= \cos(\pi·z^{2/3})$ as $z$ embraces around origin twice

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a problem I confronted and I am really struggling hard with it. Can anyone please help me out?

Consider the multi-valued function $f(z) = \cos (\pi·z^{2/3})$.

Beginning with $f(1) = -1$ the point $z$ makes double circuit embracing the origin. Determine the change in the terminal value of $f(z)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ w= \pi z^{2/3}$  then as  z makes  a double tour around the origin (argument changes $4\pi$) ; w gets to $\pi   e^{8\pi i /3 }$.

So ; $ \Delta f = \cos(-\pi /2 + i \pi \sqrt{3} /2) +1 $.